# Query only round number in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, numbers

every one.

I would like to know if it's possible in mongodb to query only round number.

I have a collection where my documents have a field: amount and this field is a number.

But I would like to get only documents where fields is a round number.

so I saw there is a `$round` but this round the number and I want only round number not rounded :P

Does anyone if you can do that with query in mongodb ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tolerance to do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          {$abs: {$subtract: ["$amount", {$round: "$amount"}]}},
          0.000001
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dQfbxZ4K34A)

*EDIT: The `$round` here is a fix by @rickhg12hs to my former `$floor`. Thanks!

Comment: But I use `$abs`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bdV-qY6eiTW

Comment: Got you and updated the answer accordingly. Thanks @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 2):

I would use [$mod](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) (num % 1) and check that the value is 0, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $mod: [
          "$num",
          1
        ]
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SpeKzfg_R7U)